# Python: Concatenate 3 arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have theee arrays, and want to combine them

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = np.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
c = np.array([[13,14,15],[16,17,18]])
```

To get:

```
array([1,2,3,7,8,9,13,14,15, 4,5,6,10,11,12,16,17,18])
```

What is the function for this ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Stack those horizontally with [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) and flatten with [`np.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) -

```
np.hstack(( a,b,c )).ravel()
```

Answer (score 9):

```
d=np.concatenate((a, b,c), axis=None)
```

The `None` parameter ensures that the arrays are flattened before concatenation (the gluing of arrays).

Comment: Please, explain why&how your answer works so that It can be more useful to less experiences programmers

Comment: The user has provided the input and the output expected, my code gives the output required